# Event Log message entry format

Tags: c#

Im trying to get entries from Event Viewer. Im getting data now, but theres ome parsin I need to know if possible. First the example:

```
Console.WriteLine("[Index]\t\t" + entry.Index +
                          "\n[EventID]\t" + entry.InstanceId +
                          "\n[TimeWritten]\t" + entry.TimeWritten +
                          "\n[MachineName]\t" + entry.MachineName +
                          "\n[Source]\t" + entry.Source +
                          "\n[UserName]\t" + entry.UserName +
                          "\n[Message]\t" + entry.Message + 
                          "\n---------------------------------------------------\n");
          }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[EventID]       4719
[TimeWritten]   8/20/2014 5:31:46 PM
[MachineName]   pcname
[Source]        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
[UserName] 
[Message]       System audit policy was changed.

Subject:
        **Security ID:**            S-1-5-18
        Account Name:           pcname$
        **Account Domain:**         WORKGROUP
        Logon ID:               0x3e7

Audit Policy Change:
        Category:               %%8273
        Subcategory:            %%12544
        Subcategory GUID:       {0CCE9215-69AE-11D9-BED3-505054503030}
        Changes:                %%8449, %%8451
```

Now what I want is to get particular pieces of information on the message like

```
**Security ID:**   **Account Domain:**.
```

Theres some method that allow me to extract only this from [message]??

Comment: It might help if you told us how you were getting the event log data, what API's you were calling, and what objects you were using.

Comment: I think you'll find this article useful http://codewala.net/2013/10/04/reading-event-logs-efficiently-using-c/

Comment: Im using information of this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5bdd8518-5509-4414-a6a3-aa2e31c1bcc1/reading-event-logs-in-c-increasing-performance?forum=csharplanguage  -- I will check the article

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
string[] mMessage = e.Entry.Message.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
for (i=0; i<=mMessage.count; i++)
{
    if (mMessage[i] == "Account Domain") 
    {
       Console.WriteLine(mMessage[i]);
    }
}
```